# React Native load image dynamically

Tags: image, reactjs, load, native

Is there any way to load an image this way?

```
var x = './img/a.jpg';
<Image source={require(x)}/>
```

I need to use this because I want to load the image dynamically.

Comment: Are you using any package manager such as Webpack ? (This is a yes if you are using `create-react-app`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can create object and use it as follows

```
const images = {
  foo: require('./img1.png'),
  bar: require('./img2.png'),
}

<Image source={images.foo} />
```

Comment: i want to use a loop for load all the image from folder
dont wanna do code for every image

Comment: @MudassirZakaria You can iterate through object keys,```for (var key in images) {
  <Image source={images[key]} />;
} ```