# React native require Image dynamically on state update with many possible options

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, state

I have a react-native-modal-dropdown with multiple options. When the user selects an option, changeImage() is triggered and the image path updates from **over 150 possible images**.

However the following solution doens't update the Image component because react native doesn't allow dynamic require.

```
const [imagePath,setImagePath] = useState('defaultImg')

// newImg, is a dynamic string which changes with user input
// "assets/images" folder has over 150 images

const changeImage = (newImg) {
  // if valid path, change path
  setImagePath(newImage)
}

return(
 <Image
    style={styles.imageStyle}
    resizeMode="center"
    source={require('../assets/images/' + imagePath + '.png')}
 />)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names) solution is not scalable, neither is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792695/react-native-load-image-dynamically).

I've seen some solutions using json and helper methods but I couldn't get them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out using an "images.js" helper file.

In "App.js" I'm updating the image path depending on a "target" state value.

```
import {getImage} from './images';

// Image is updated based on this value
const [target,setTarget] = useState("default");

// Default image path
const [imagePath,setImagePath] = useState({path: getImage('default')}) 

useEffect(() => {
  setImagePath({
    path: getImage(target);
  });
},[target])


return(
  <View>
    <Image source={imagePath.path} />
  </View>
)
```

And here's "images.js" which is in the same path as a folder called "pictures":

```
export function getImage(input) {
  switch (input) {
    case "value_1": return require('./pictures/Picture1.png');
    case "value_2": return require('./pictures/Picture2.png');
    case "value_3": return require('./pictures/Picture3.png');
    ...
    case "value_149": return require('./pictures/Picture149.png');
    case "value_150": return require('./pictures/Picture150.png');
    case "default": return require('./pictures/placeholder.png');
  }
}
```

Creating the above function can be tedious so I created a python script that outputs the switch result programmatically to an output file and I simply copied pasted the output into this file.

Comment: it should be setImagePath instead of setImage in useEffect